# LESS, compile issues with variables inside CSS urls

Tags: compiler-errors, less, quotes, word-wrap

I've created a small LESS based mixin for outputting images in either standard or retina format. I can't get my head around wrapping variables inside some of the CSS urls that goes along with this - when I compile the code below I end up with **url('http://sample.com/images/'sprite@2x.png'')**. Both background properties seem to need to be wrapped inside quotes in order for the compiler to fetch the variables. While this works, as I try and set the background property for the high ppi scenario I end up with these extra single quotes around the filename.

```
.image(@path, @w: auto, @h: auto) {
    background-image: url('@{base-url}/images/@{path}');
    @path_2x: ~`"@{path}".split('.').slice(0, "@{path}".split('.').length - 1).join(".") + "@2x" + "." + "@{path}".split('.')["@{path}".split('.').length - 1]`;

    @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
        background-image: url('@{base-url}/images/@{path_2x}');
        background-size: @w @h;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are passing the `@path` as a string itself, something like:

```
.image('sprite.png');
```

You can do one of two things:

### 1) Escape it at time of call (less user friendly)

```
.image(~'sprite.png');
```

### 2) Modify the javascript to not add the extra quotes (user friendly)

This keeps the unescaped call `.image('sprite.png');`, but notice here I have changed your `"@{path}"` to just `@{path}` since the path is already being passed as a string, so `@{path}` already resolves to a string and is capable of string operations. By adding the quotes, you are essentially making the path from `'sprite.png'` to `"'sprite.png'"` which is then leaving the extra quotes.

```
@path_2x: ~`@{path}.split('.').slice(0, "@{path}".split('.').length - 1).join(".") + "@2x" + "." + @{path}.split('.')[@{path}.split('.').length - 1]`;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been banging my head against the wall on this. The second route seems to be a far better option.